# What is the preferred way to do this in WCF Data Services

Tags: wcf-data-services

I understood that WCF Data Services is based on OData model (of course, REST).  It seems like it is great to work with Entity manipulations (like CRUD).

Imagine that I am developing an ASP.NET web app, and on tab out of a textbox, I would like to validate something (say for uniqueness of email).  And these are the kinds of things which will be quite common in any development (not just working with Entities always).

How can I achieve such types of operations using WCF Data Services?  Do I need to work with Operations instead of working with Resources (say Entities)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your own interceptor for this resource. You can find some help on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744842.aspx)